# Case when devuelve muchos registros y sólo busco uno

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Estoy haciendo una consulta en SQL Server y tengo un problema con el `case when`.

Dentro de la sentencia, me devuelve un valor (porque es un count de 40 filas) pero cuando me hace el `case when` me devuelve como valor el mismo número de filas (las 40).

Aquí va:

```
select (
    case when
        ((select count(*) from tabla where id='A') / (select count(*) from tabla)) > 0.15) then 'A'
    when
((select count(*) from tabla where id='B') / (select count(*) from tabla)) > 0.15) then 'B'
    else 'VERDE'
    end
) 
from tabla
```

Solo quiero que me aparezca el count de la columna siendo "A" dividido por el count de todos los registros.

Si lo hago individualmente, la cuenta sale bien, pero es con el case cuando salen 40 registros.

Comment: y es correcto.. el select lo hace para cada registro de tabla que debe tener 40 filas...

Comment: Estas esperando recibir un solo registro como resultado?

Comment: Seria bueno agregar la estructura de tu tabla actual

Comment: pero y cómo hago para tener solo una fila? Solo quiero que me aparezca el count de la columna siendo "A" dividido por el count de todos los registros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu select actual se ejecuta por cada fila de tabla. Por lo tanto, ejecuta el case para cada fila y devuelve lo que estas viendo en este momento.

No tengo forma de probar lo que buscas, pero creo que asi te devolveria un solo registro, el primero, que es lo que estas buscando.

```
select top 1 (
case when
((select count(*) from tabla where id='A') / (select count(*) from tabla)) > 0.15) then 'A'
when
((select count(*) from tabla where id='B') / (select count(*) from tabla)) > 0.15) then 'B'
else 'VERDE'
end
) 
from tabla
```

Comment: Sí, también lo he probado. Porque esto lo estoy metiendo dentro de un "insert into" y el top 1 lo omite y termina copiando los 40 registros. ¿Me explico?

Comment: te das cuenta que entonces no tiene nada que ver lo que preguntaste con lo que estas haciendo? puedes reescribir la pregunta, aclarando todo lo que estas haciendo, porque lo estas haciendo de esa forma, y asi tal vez podemos ayudarte mejor?

Comment: Y aclara que probaste asi no te damos como solucion algo que ya hiciste!

Comment: Vale, perdón, efectivamente he probado y he puesto el "select top 1" al inicio y funciona. Lo tenía puesto inicialmente dentro del case one:
select top 1(
case when
((select count(*) from tabla where id='A') / (select count(*) from tabla)) > 0.15) then 'A'
when
((select count(*) from tabla where id='B') / (select count(*) from tabla)) > 0.15) then 'B'
else 'VERDE'
end
) 
from tabla

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: ok.. si la respuesta sirvio por favor aceptala. saludos. y aclara mejor la pregunta la proxima vez ;)